# Where on earth is this? (Apricot, cherry and azalea blossoms in South-West China)

Tags: china, where-on-earth, identify-this

[BBC News](http://www.bbc.com/news/av/world-asia-china-43443968/blossom-in-south-west-china-captured-by-drone) put out this video:

> **Blossom in south-west China captured by drone**
>
> Apricot, cherry and azalea blossom create a stunning landscape in south-west China.

South-west China is a big area though, it hardly helps matters.

Any idea where this video was taken?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Gui'an New Area, Guizhou

贵安新区，贵州.

Here's a [Xinhua](http://www.xinhuanet.com/english/2018-03/14/c_137038994_4.htm) article talking about it.

---

I did a reverse image search on Google, using a screenshot of the video:

[image: hey]

Which also returned this funky [Thai news article](http://www.tnamcot.com/view/5aac9f9de3f8e420ab43f0ec).

Then I took the text:

> จีน 17 มี.ค.61- ดอกไม้บานสะพรั่งทั่วจีนมีนักท่องเที่ยวจำนวนมากแห่เที่ยวชมความสวยงามของดอกไม้นานาชนิดที่กำลังผลิบาน ต้อนรับฤดูใบไม้ผลิ
>
> หลายพื้นที่ในประเทศจีน มีนักท่องเที่ยวจำนวนมากไปเที่ยวชมความสวยงามของดอกไม้นานาชนิด ที่กำลังผลิบาน ต้อนรับฤดูใบไม้ผลิ ที่มณฑลกุ้ยโจว ทางตะวันตกเฉียงใต้ ดอกซากุระกำลังบานอวดโฉมในพื้นที่ขนาดใหญ่ดึงดูดนักท่องเที่ยวให้มาเที่ยวชมและถ่ายรูปเป็นที่ระลึก และบางพื้นที่ยังมีทุ่งดอกไม้หลากสีสันให้ชื่นชมความงาม ส่วนที่มณฑลส่านซีทางภาคเหนือ ดอกท้อสีขาวอมชมพูกำลังผลิบาน มีนักท่องเที่ยวมาชมกันอย่างไม่ขาดสาย ขณะที่มณฑลอันฮุย ทางภาคตะวันออก ดอกชวนชมสีแดงก็กำลังบานสะพรั่งสวยงามไม่แพ้กัน.-สำนักข่าวไทย

and Google Translated it:

> Mar 17, 2006 - Flowers bloom throughout China, many tourists flock to see the beauty of the flowers are blooming. Welcome to spring
>
> Many areas in China. There are many tourists to visit the beautiful flowers. Blossoming Welcome to spring Guizhou Province Southwest Sakura is blooming in a large area, attract tourists to visit and take photos as souvenirs. And some areas also have colorful flowers to admire beauty. The northern Shaanxi Province Pink flowers are pink blossoming. There are tourists to see each other. As Anhui Province Eastern Red Azalea flowers are blooming equally beautiful.

The only place in SW China was: **Guizhou Province**.

Searching: `Cherry blossom Guizhou` gave me the Xinhua article above.

Comment: Can you expand on why the news article is "funky"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Because I find the Thai script quite funky, I guess!